# Python Deap Lib TypeError while compiling fitness

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, exception, deap

I don't know why i got an exception with my python software (i'm running under windows):

```
File "C:\Users\lumy\PycharmProjects\EternityPuzzle\puzzle.py", line 94, in log_stats
  self.record = self.stats.compile(self.population)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\deap\tools\support.py", line 237, in compile
  record[name] = stats.compile(data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\deap\tools\support.py", line 204, in compile
  values = tuple(self.key(elem) for elem in data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\deap\tools\support.py", line 204, in <genexpr>
  values = tuple(self.key(elem) for elem in data)
File "C:\Users\lumy\PycharmProjects\EternityPuzzle\puzzle.py", line 73, in <lambda>
  stats2 = tools.Statistics(key=lambda ind: ind.fitness_group.values)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\deap\base.py", line 181, in getValues
  return tuple(map(truediv, self.wvalues, self.weights))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

I was trying to log two differents fitness.

so the getValues function is in the Fitness Object:

```
def getValues(self):
    print self.wvalues, self.weights
    return tuple(map(truediv, self.wvalues, self.weights))
```

Output:

```
() (1.0,)
```

If I understand, wvalues should contains all the old values, but it's seems to be empty the first time and.
My Code sample looks like:

```
 from deap import base
 from deap import creator
 from deap import tools

 creator.create("FitnessInd", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
 creator.create("FitnessGroup", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
 creator.create("Individual", ind.Ind, fitness_ind=creator.FitnessInd, fitness_group=creator.FitnessGroup)
 toolbox.register("new_individual", creator.Individual)
 toolbox.register("desk", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.new_individual)
 population = toolbox.desk(n=len(arr))
 stats2 = tools.Statistics(key=lambda ind: ind.fitness_group.values)
 stats1 = tools.Statistics(key=lambda ind: ind.fitness_ind.values)
 stats = tools.MultiStatistics(fitness_ind=stats1, fitness_group=stats2)
 stats.register("min", min)
 logbook = tools.Logbook()

 values = eval_solution(population)
 for ind, v in zip(population, values):
   ind.fitness_ind.value = v,
   ind.fitness_group.value = v,

 record = stats.compile(population)
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: How come `truediv` doesn't work have a value?

Comment: not sure what you're asking but truediv is a builtin and apparently:
map(truediv, self.wvalues, self.weights)) give:
truediv(self.wvalues[0], self.weights[0]) when self.wvalues = () so truediv get a None arguments